# YES ,No image set in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to run a code as  when the code is true the right image should display and when it is false it should display the wrong sign.
example when Beef jerky, chopped and formed should show right image
data should get it from database

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    int random = arc4random() % arrimg.count;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrimg objectAtIndex:random]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    [cell.accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];

} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    int random = arc4random() % arrimg.count;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrimg objectAtIndex:random]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     //        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Yes_check.png"]];
     //        [cell.accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
}
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:99.0/255 green:170.0/255 blue:229.0/255 alpha:1.0];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:15];

return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Whats your current requirement? In Uitableview you need to display two images one is true and another one is false?

Answer (score -1):

Please Make Below Steps:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
if([checkmarkArray[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"]) // Wrong image displayed here
{
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wrongImage.png"]];
    [cell.accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];

}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trueImage.png"]];
    [cell.accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
}

}
```

Comment: Answers should not just be code. Explain what was wrong and what fixes were needed.

Comment: I want to fetch data from database